# Sequel of "Tame topology and o-minimal structures"

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, model-theory

In the opening of the well-known book "Tame topology and o-minimal structures", the author (van den Dries) repeatedly claims that further results will be developed in a sequel to this book, who will use more advanced model theory and tools from other fields such as differential topology. I've tried to find the aforementioned sequel, but nothing came up to match the description. Has such a sequel been published?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first long-awaited sequel not to appear....

Comment: It didn't appear, but there's a draft of it floating around the world.